# IFTTT weekly out of office reply

Tags: gmail, reply, ifttt

I'm a complete programming noob but I'm trying to figure out how to create a recipe in platform.ifttt.com to send a Gmail out of office reply every Thursday from 5pm to Friday 11:59pm. I wrote some code (which isn't working...) that I hoped would work at least for Friday:

```
var day = Meta.currentUserTime.day()
if (day = 0,1,2,3,4,6) {
 Gmail.sendAnEmail.skip()
}
```

Can someone tell me why this code does not work?

Also, any help on how to use moments.js to point to the exact time range that I am trying to use as a trigger?

Comment: Can you link to the IFTTT docs on how to create this filter code?

Comment: https://platform.ifttt.com/docs/applets#using-filter-code